# C# How to call a post API by "PostAsJsonAsync" when the specification of header and body of this API is given?

Tags: c#, http-headers, postasync

I am learning to use API and I have been given the specification of the URL, header and body of an API. The example is shown as follow

```
url: api/getRate
hearder:{
  "msgNo": "abc123",
  "receiver": "Customer_A"
}
body:{
  "dateTime": "2023/08/19 18:00:00",
  "Currency": "USD",
  "Ratetype": "COST"
}
```

How should I use C# method `PostAsJsonAsync` to get the result by this API?

Currently, I have the following code. Please tell me whether it is a correct way to use  `PostAsJsonAsync` in the aforementioned situation.

```
var posturl = "api/getRate";
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("msgNo", "abc123");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("receiver", "Customer_A");
var requestBody = new {
    "dateTime": "2023/08/19 18:00:00",
    "Currency": "USD",
    "Ratetype": "COST"};
var response = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(posturi, requestBody).Result;
```

Comment: Have you tried your code and see whether it is workable or not? While I don't think the `requestBody` is correct as you are using anonymous type, it should be: `var requestBody = new { dateTime =  "2023/08/19 18:00:00", /* Following properties */ };`

Comment: My code is not workable. And I am curious how to set request hearder and request body before calling "PostAsJsonAsync()"

Comment: What is the error, if any, that you get when compiling and/or executing that code.

Comment: read this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0